# Foundation (Button Classes) not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I'm using Rails 4 with Foundation but I have the impression that Foundation is not working correctly.

The typeface is not Helvetica and then I added some buttonclasses and the button just stays the same...

Here is the code for the button:

```
<%= button_to 'Neue Provision', new_provision_path, class: 'button success radius large' %><br>
```

Any ideas what I should check or look for?

Comment: CSS inspector. Are your stylesheets even loading?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.0 removed the assets group from Gemfile.

Run:

```
     rails g foundation:install
```

Which should automatically correctly configure your app.

If not you can manually configure like so:

Add:

```
    /*= require foundation */
```

to your main css file or add to your main .js file:

```
    //= require foundation
    $(document).foundation();
```

Another issue can be that you're either overriding your foundation.css with custom styles or you simply don't have the foundation.css file. Remember that stylesheets are read top to bottom and the styles appearing later will take precedence.

As per the [Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/rails.html).

Comment: When you inspect element on your button, what styles are present?

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Just inspected the button: No styles at all :-(

Comment: This sounds like a case of stylesheets not being injected properly. How are you calling the foundation.css file in your app?

Comment: to be honest: I don't know